# when run "python setup.py install", I meet "error:[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, uncertainty

I want to install Third-party library "uncertainty-baselines" in my conda virtual environment "uncertainty_bl".I want to run "Batchensemble" example.

```
C:\Users\70987\Desktop\uncertainty-baselines-main>conda activate uncertainty_BL
(uncertainty_BL) C:\Users\70987\Desktop\uncertainty-baselines-main>python setup.py install
running install
E:\Anaconda\envs\uncertainty_BL\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
E:\Anaconda\envs\uncertainty_BL\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing uncertainty_baselines.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to uncertainty_baselines.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to uncertainty_baselines.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to uncertainty_baselines.egg-info\top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'uncertainty_baselines.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
adding license file 'LICENSE'
writing manifest file 'uncertainty_baselines.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\uncertainty_baselines
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\uncertainty_baselines\datasets
copying build\lib\uncertainty_baselines\datasets\aptos.py -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\uncertainty_baselines\datasets
...
byte-compiling build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\uncertainty_baselines\datasets\aptos.py to aptos.cpython-39.pyc
...
creating build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying uncertainty_baselines.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying uncertainty_baselines.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying uncertainty_baselines.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying uncertainty_baselines.egg-info\requires.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
copying uncertainty_baselines.egg-info\top_level.txt -> build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\EGG-INFO
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
creating 'dist\uncertainty_baselines-0.0.7-py3.9.egg' and adding 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' to it
removing 'build\bdist.win-amd64\egg' (and everything under it)
Processing uncertainty_baselines-0.0.7-py3.9.egg
Removing e:\anaconda\envs\uncertainty_bl\lib\site-packages\uncertainty_baselines-0.0.7-py3.9.egg
error: [WinError 32]  Another program is using this file and the process cannot access it。: 'e:\\anaconda\\envs\\uncertainty_bl\\lib\\site-packages\\uncertainty_baselines-0.0.7-py3.9.egg'
```

Why I meet the error? How to deal with it?